# How to have double backslash `\\` in vscode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to get this snippet to work :

```
"General matrix": {
    "prefix": "general-matrix-n-n-with-a-elements",
    "body": [
        "\\begin{equation}",
        "\t \\begin{bmatrix}",
        "\t\t a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \\dots  & a_{1n} \\\\ ",
        "\t\t a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \\dots  & a_{2n} \\\\ ",
        "\t\t \\vdots & \\vdots & \\vdots & \\ddots & \\vdots \\\\ ",
        "\t\t a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \\dots  & a_{nn}",
        "\t \\end{bmatrix}",
        "\\end{equation}",
    ],
    "description": "General n by n matrix"
```

So that it formats to this

```
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots  & a_{1n} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots  & a_{2n} \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots  & a_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
```

But the backslashes are formatting to this

```
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots  & a_{1n} \ 
            a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots  & a_{2n} \ 
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \ 
            a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots  & a_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
```

Note that there's not a double `\\` at the end of the lines but a single `\`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add two more backslashes as in:

```
"General matrix": {
    "prefix": "general-matrix-n-n-with-a-elements",
    "body": [
        "\\begin{equation}",
        "\t \\begin{bmatrix}",
        "\t\t a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \\dots  & a_{1n} \\\\\\ ",
        "\t\t a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \\dots  & a_{2n} \\\\\\ ",
        "\t\t \\vdots & \\vdots & \\vdots & \\ddots & \\vdots \\\\\\ ",
        "\t\t a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \\dots  & a_{nn}",
        "\t \\end{bmatrix}",
        "\\end{equation}",
    ],
    "description": "General n by n matrix"
  }
```

Each backslash in a snippet that you want printed needs to be **double-escaped**, so that is 2 extra per each backslash for a total of 6 if you want 2 outputted.